# Adicionar valores na array a partir de um JSON que possua o valor de uma variável

Tags: javascript, html, json

Criei um um variável chamada `arrayFaixaD`:

```
var arrayFaixaD = new Array();
```

e criei um `for` que lê o ficheiro JSON todo:

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
```

dentro desse `for` eu pus alguns `if`:

```
if(json[i].Faixa == "faixaD"){
   arrayFaixaD[1] = json[i].Nome;
   arrayFaixaD[2] = json[i].Idade;
   arrayFaixaD[3] = json[i].Localidade;
}
```

depois escrevi este `if` para dentro dele por as funções todas da `option`:

```
if($('#myselect').val() == "faixaD"){
   document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = arrayFaixaD;
}
```

Esse `if` faz com que escreva as informações dentro de um parágrafo identificado com um `id`:

```
<p id="demoA"></p>
```

e está tudo a funcionar. O problema é que dentro do JSON existe mais que um array com a `faixaD`:

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "Nome": "Lucia Rodrigues",
        "Idade": "48",
        "Localidade": "Lagoa",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
        "Idade": "46",
        "Localidade": "Ilha Terceira",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "Nome": "Maria Eufrázia",
        "Idade": "83",
        "Localidade": "Terena",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "Nome": "Luzia Rosado",
        "Idade": "80",
        "Localidade": "Terena",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "Nome": "Fernanda",
        "Idade": "70",
        "Localidade": "Oeiras",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
        "Idade": "48",
        "Localidade": "Ilha Terceira",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "Nome": "Helena Cabrita",
        "Idade": "60",
        "Localidade": "Cruz de Pau",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "Não"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "Nome": "Fernando Cruz",
        "Idade": "60",
        "Localidade": "Porto",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "Nome": "Ana Maria Silva",
        "Idade": "53",
        "Localidade": "Ilha Terceira",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "13",
        "Nome": "Ana Paula",
        "Idade": "40",
        "Localidade": "Salamonde",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "Não"
    }
```

Mas ele só escreve uma pessoa e eu queria que ele escreve se todas essas pessoas que estão dentro da `faixaD`. Como posso chegar a esse resultado?

Comment: Por favor, melhore o título da sua pergunta. "Ajuda com código" é um péssimo título e não retrata o contexto da pergunta. Talvez seja interessante ler [Como escolher um bom título?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4394/5878)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa fazer é um `.push()` (adicionar valores na array). Da forma que está fazendo, você está criando e sobrescrevendo as posições [1], [2] e [3] da array, e no final do laço irá sobrar apenas o último objeto do JSON, cujo valor de `Nome` é "Ana Paula", e ainda vai faltar a posição [0] da array (toda array começa do [0]).

No caso do `.innerHTML`, o resultado será que irá imprimir no `p#demoA` todos os valores da array separados por vírgula. Como na pergunta você não explica como quer o resultado, esta é a solução:

```js
var json = [{
        "id": "1",
        "Nome": "Lucia Rodrigues",
        "Idade": "48",
        "Localidade": "Lagoa",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
        "Idade": "46",
        "Localidade": "Ilha Terceira",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "Nome": "Maria Eufrázia",
        "Idade": "83",
        "Localidade": "Terena",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "Nome": "Luzia Rosado",
        "Idade": "80",
        "Localidade": "Terena",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "Nome": "Fernanda",
        "Idade": "70",
        "Localidade": "Oeiras",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
        "Idade": "48",
        "Localidade": "Ilha Terceira",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "Nome": "Helena Cabrita",
        "Idade": "60",
        "Localidade": "Cruz de Pau",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "Não"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "Nome": "Fernando Cruz",
        "Idade": "60",
        "Localidade": "Porto",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "Nome": "Ana Maria Silva",
        "Idade": "53",
        "Localidade": "Ilha Terceira",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "???"
    },
    {
        "id": "13",
        "Nome": "Ana Paula",
        "Idade": "40",
        "Localidade": "Salamonde",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Tribunal": "Não"
    }];
    

$("#myselect").on("change", function(){
 
   var arrayFaixaD = new Array();

   for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
   
      if(json[i].Faixa == "faixaD"){
         arrayFaixaD.push(json[i].Nome, json[i].Idade, json[i].Localidade);
      }
   }
   if($('#myselect').val() == "faixaD"){
      document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = arrayFaixaD;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
   <option value="">Selecione...</option>
   <option value="faixaD">faixaD</option>
</select>
<p id="demoA"></p>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Sam!